# Deadlocks related to scheduling

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, concurrency

On the [Oracle docs for multithreading](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-5257/6je9h0347/index.html#guide-ix965) they have this paragraph about deadlocks when trying to require a lock:

> Because there is no guaranteed order in which locks are acquired, a
>   problem in threaded programs is that a particular thread never
>   acquires a lock, even though it seems that it should.
>
> This usually happens when the thread that holds the lock releases it,
>   lets a small amount of time pass, and then reacquires it. Because the
>   lock was released, it might seem that the other thread should acquire
>   the lock. But, because nothing blocks the thread holding the lock, it
>   continues to run from the time it releases the lock until it
>   reacquires the lock, and so no other thread is run.

Just to make sure I understood this, I tried to write this out in code (let me know if this is a correct interpretation):

```c++
#include <mutex>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

std::mutex m;

void f()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m); // acquire the lock
    std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << " now has the mutex\n";

    lock.unlock(); // release the lock
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2)); // sleep for a while

    lock.lock(); // reacquire the lock
    std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << " has the mutex after sleep\n";
}

int main()
{
    std::thread(f).join(); // thread A
    std::thread(f).join(); // thread B
}
```

So what the quote above is saying is that the time during which the lock is released and the thread is sleeping (like the code above) is not sufficient to guarantee a thread waiting on the lock to acquire it? How does this relate to deadlocks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The document is addressing a specific kind of fairness problem and is lumping it into its discussions about deadlock. The document correctly defines deadlock to mean a "permanent blocking of a set of threads". It then describes a slightly less obvious way of achieving the permanent blocking condition.

In the scenario described, assume two threads attempt to acquire the same lock simultaneously. Only one will win, so call it **`W`**, and the other loses, so call it **`L`**.  The loser is put to sleep to wait its turn to get the lock.

The quoted text says that **`L`** may never get a chance to get the lock, even if it is released by **`W`**.

The reason this might happen is the lock does not impose fairness over which thread has acquired it. The lock is more than happy to let **`W`** acquire and release it forever. If **`W`** is implemented in such a way that it does not need to context switch after it releases the lock, it may just end up acquiring the lock again before **`L`** has a chance to wake up to see if the lock is available.

So, in the code below, if `W_thread` wins the initial race against `L_thread`, `L_thread` is effectively deadlocked, even though in theory it could acquire the lock between iterations of `W_thread`.

```
void W_thread () {
    for (;;) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m);
        //...
    }
}

void L_thread () {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m);
    //...
}
```

The document recommends using `thr_yield()` to force a context switch to another thread. This API is specific to Solaris/SunOS. The POSIX version of it is called `sched_yield()`, although some UNIX versions (including Linux) provide a wrapper called `pthread_yield()`.

In C++11, this is accomplished via [`std::this_thread::yield()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/yield).

Comment: The solution in the document says to use `thr_yield`. How might this be done in C++?

Comment: I addressed `thr_yield()` in an update at the bottom of the answer.